# Given parent/advertiser data, how can I get the list of parents where ALL advertisers meet a certain condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, case, having

I have a table containing parent_ids, advertiser_ids and number values. I want to write a query that gives me the parent ids where **all advertisers under that parent** have a number value greater than 90.

I'm struggling to do this in a streamlined way. I've been trying an assortment of queries, but I'm worried my answer is missing some output values (still testing):

```
SELECT parent
FROM tbl_a
GROUP BY 1
HAVING sum(case when num_dark_days BETWEEN 90 AND 120 
                then 1 else 0 end
          ) = count(advertiser_id)
```

```
tbl_a:
parent  advertiser  num_dark_days
A           1               5
A           2               50
A           3               40
A           4               90
A           5               130
B           6               95
B           7               99
B           8               200
B           9               102
C           10              89
D           11              96
```

I want to get back something that looks like this:

```
parent      full_dark
A             no
B             yes
C             no
D             yes
```

(using the logic of this ‘pretend' in between table)

```
parent    num_dark_advertisers    total_advertiser_per_parent
A            2                    5
B            4                    4
C            0                    1
D            1                    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need a `CASE` expression, such as:

```
SELECT parent,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) FILTER (num_dark_days >= 90)
             THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no'
        END)
FROM tbl_a
GROUP BY parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Few corrections from the other user's answer:

```
SELECT parent,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT
                  (CASE 
                   WHEN num_dark_days >= 90 
                   THEN 1 
                   ELSE 0 
                   END) = COUNT(advertiser_id)
             THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no'
        END) AS 'full_dark'
FROM tbl_a
GROUP BY parent;
```